# Method injection with optional class?

Tags: java, spring

```
@Bean
public Mybean create(MyServiceToInject myservice) {
    bean = Mybean();
    if (myservice != null)
       bean.setMyservice(myservice);
}
```

How can I tell `spring` that `MyServiceToInject` may be null and must not be injected if missing?

Comment: Add `@Autowired(required=false)` to the method argument.

Comment: `The annotation @Autowired is disallowed for this location` if I add it to the `create` method.

Comment: Add to method instead of argument or add an `@Autowired(required=false)` field to your configuration class.

Comment: I don't really understand your code, you construct a bean, pass the dependency into the constructor and also call a setter? Why? You already pass it as a constructor argument...

Comment: Sorry that was a typo, of course I won't pass it as a constructor argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to just autowire it in your bean (not in the bean configuration):

```
@Component
public class MyBean {
    @Autowired(required=false)
    private MyServiceToInject myService;
}
```

You can also autowire in the configuration class, but this seems unnecessary in this case:

```
@Autowired(required=false)
private MyServiceToInject myService;

@Bean
public Mybean create() {
    bean = Mybean();
    if (myservice != null)
       bean.setMyservice(myService);
}
```